# mixed partial derivative of a function

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Find second order mixed partial derivative, $\displaystyle \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial y \partial x}$ of $\displaystyle \frac{x \log(y)}{ye^x}$

I tried differentiating it wrt $x$ (keeping $y$ constant) and then differentiating the result wrt $y$ (keeping $x$ as constant) but my answer is not matching.

Comment: It is not a partial derivative.

Comment: Also, what is $f$?

Comment: $\dfrac{\mathrm d^2f}{\mathrm dy\ \mathrm dx}$ is really just $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}\dfrac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dx}$.

Comment: What is your answer, and what is the book's answer?

Comment: Is the answer $$f_{xy} = \frac{(1-x)(1- \ln y)}{y^{2} e^{x}}$$?

Comment: Right...go ahead and show us what you did (and what the book said), and we can probably find the mistake pretty quickly. (About 20% of the time, the mistake is "the answer book is wrong and you're right." )